# Add Attachment to Rules Email - Drupal 8

Tags: 8, rules

I am trying to set up a simple rule in D8 that when a new node is created, an email is sent out that includes an attachment from the file system.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what have you tried, and which part are you still missing or doesn't work as desired/expected? Please improve (edit) your question to include something that shows the rule you have so far.

Comment: "that includes an attachment from the file system." is this one file used every time. Is it a dynamically generated files... We need more info to help

Answer (score 1):

Drupal core does not provide a way to send HTML e-mail or to send e-mail with attachments. Thus, you will have to use a separate module which has this functionality AND which integrates with Rules. One such module is [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail). Mime Mail does have a D8 port, but it's not complete. When it is complete, Rules in D8 is ready and able to use that functionality.